# Add configurable swatches inside Related Product block in magento2 product view page

Tags: magento2, configurable-swatches

I have added below code inside the following path:

/app/design/frontend/magento/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

//code inside related product block

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related" name="catalog.product.related" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/related.phtml">                  
 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="related.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" as="default"/>
    <block class="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable" as="configurable" template="Magento_Swatches::product/listing/renderer.phtml" />
</block>
</block>
```

To get swatches inside related block i update code in below path:

/app/design/frontend/magento/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/related.phtml

add below code to show a configurable option but can not get this.

```
<div class="product details product-item-details">
  ....
<?php echo $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_item); ?>
```

Comment: I think this issue with Magento version.

Comment: It might be possible because above code working on the latest version of Magento 2.3.0 but not working on 2.2.1 version .